# Button Moving Website Content

Tags: html, css, button, scrollbar

I want to make a menu and when someone clicks on my menu it will move them down to the content he clicked cause the site is long it would be easier that way. Any ideas/ suggestions?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table  width="650"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="" usemap="#Map" width="650" height="84" alt="plasio.gr" style="display:block; vertical-align:bottom;background-color:#FFD6CC;color:#000000;text-align:center;font-size:20px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"></td>
    </tr>

    </table>

    <map name="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="-51,-2,174,39" href="link1">
<area shape="rect" coords="85,53,149,86" href="link2">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using **Anchor Links**

Using anchor links you can link to a specific part of a website.
You use the **hashtag(#)** to link within a page. When clicking on the link it will automatically go to that part of the page that has either an `id` or a `name` that is equal to the text that follows after the hashtag(#)

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n1v7rqts/)

**Example**

```
<a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#link2">Link 2</a>

<div>
    <a name="link1"></a>
    Section 1
</div>

<div id="link2">
    Section 2
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me great! But how i can make it center the image where i link?

Comment: I don't quite get what you're asking for. Could you elaborate?

Comment: when i click the link it goes at the section i want but i want to be able to move the height of the scrollbar manually is that possible?\

Comment: I'm still not quite clear on what you want to achive. Do you not want the scrollbar position to change automatically but instead you have to change it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Maybe you have a page called `page.html` with the code below

```
<div id="part1">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

<div id="part2">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

<div id="part3">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

To move to a specified section make a `<a class="button" href="page.html#part1"">Part 1</a>` or

`<a class="button" href="page.html#part2"">Part 2</a>`

Alternatively,you could use jquery parallax plugins like this one https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax  or this other https://github.com/balupton/jquery-scrollto

You can use jquery easing to have some nice effects as your scroll.